# Django REST framework smiple jwt add custom payload data and access it in route

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

I am generating a custom jwt token for authentication using RefreshToken.for_user(user) at the time of login and registration. I can access user using request.user in the API endpoint but I also want to add user type in the payload data, so that I can access the user_type field in the API endpoint.

This is what I am doing.

```
def get_tokens_for_user(user):
  refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
  return {
      'refresh': str(refresh),
      'access': str(refresh.access_token),

class UserRegistrationView(APIView):
  def post(self, request, format=None):
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    token = get_tokens_for_user(user)
    return Response({ 'token':token })
```

Now at endpoint

```
class FileDetail(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    def get(self, request, pk):
        user = request.user
        user_type = request.user_type // this data I want to save in the payload and get here.
```

so I want user_type and other data at API endpoint from jwt payload data

Comment: If it's inside Django project, you should store in db and access `request.user.user_type` instead. JWT payload is meant for the client to read, not the server.

Comment: actually, the same user can log in as different types as a patient or doctor so he selects patient or doctor at login I need this also.

Answer (score 0):

this is how you add custom payload.

- import TokenOBtainPairSerializer

  **from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer**

class CustomeTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):

```
    def validate(self, attrs):
        data = super(CustomeTokenObtainPairSerializer, self).validate(attrs)
        if self.user.is_active is not True:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({"message": "User is not active."})
        data.update({
            'username': self.user.username,   # username
            'email': self.user.email,       # email
            'mobile_number': self.user.mobile_number  # mobile_number
                **## here add more fields as you want**
        })
        return data
```

Comment: then how to generate a token at the time of registration? currently, I am using token = get_tokens_for_user(user) to generate a token in the registration route.

Comment: this is what on generating custom payload at the time of registrations

Comment: you are manually creating token

Comment: yes at the time of registration can you give an example of how to use CustomeTokenObtainPairSerializer to generate a token in the registration route?

Comment: https://github.com/tanveer-ahmad74/Dummy it generates automatically tokens here you can see and you can find more intresting repo related to DRF